# How do I index the cells within a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I used this code

```
nonzero = ucla_all[ucla_all['ADJUSTMENTS']!= 0]
cond = (nonzero.groupby(['SERV_CODE', 'CPT_CODE']).mean())['ADJUSTMENTS']
cond
```

to display this table

```
SERV_CODE  CPT_CODE
2110       90834      -600.000000
           90837      -421.000000
2111       90849      -110.000000
           90853      -130.000000
2220       90834      -800.000000
           90837      -416.534804
           90849      -110.000000
```

How do I index the third column?

Answer (score 0):

```py
nonzero = ucla_all[ucla_all['ADJUSTMENTS']!= 0]
cond = (nonzero.groupby(['SERV_CODE', 'CPT_CODE']).mean())['ADJUSTMENTS']

cond.columns = ['SERV_CODE', 'CPT_CODE', 'NEW_COLUMN_NAME']
```

```
SERV_CODE  CPT_CODE   NEW_COLUMN_NAME
2110       90834      -600.000000
           90837      -421.000000
2111       90849      -110.000000
           90853      -130.000000
2220       90834      -800.000000
           90837      -416.534804
           90849      -110.000000
```

Comment: You might want to edit your suggestion into the code snippet from the question so that future users don't need clarification on where to put it.